# apache2 and mysql automatically starts up after out of memory failure

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

I have a server where I'm having out of memory problems. This is causing apache and mysql to be killed, according to the message log.

```
kernel: [29992047.769005] Out of memory: Kill process 13541 (httpd) score 10 or sacrifice child
kernel: [29992047.769005] Killed process 13541 (httpd) total-vm:70432kB, anon-rss:11016kB, file-rss:168kB
```

Oddly (although a good thing) it starts up automatically and I can't figure out how. I need to investigate the out of memory errors still but I'm clueless on how it actually starts up automatically.

I've setup apache and mysql on my own Amazon EC2 small instance. There is no cron job on this or any other automatic script other than the usual chkconfig setup for boot time.

Mostly curiosity at this point but it would be useful to know when and how apache and mysql started up again. Might be useful for my other services as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clues for you:

- Are you running [`monit`](http://mmonit.com/monit/)?
- Or [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) with `autorestart` turned
  on?
- Or Nagios with an [Event
  Handlers](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html)?
- ...

You can also using the [`auditd`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) to set a watch on the Apache binary file:

```
auditctl -w /usr/sbin/httpd -p x -k apache-binary-file
```

then find out who called it:

```
# ausearch -f /usr/sbin/httpd
----
time->Tue Mar 19 05:23:22 2013
type=PATH msg=audit(1363674202.844:241): item=1 name=(null) inode=3237 dev=fd:00 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:ld_so_t:s0
type=PATH msg=audit(1363674202.844:241): item=0 name="/usr/sbin/httpd" inode=14695 dev=fd:00 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:httpd_exec_t:s0
type=CWD msg=audit(1363674202.844:241):  cwd="/root"
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1363674202.844:241): argc=1 a0="/usr/sbin/httpd"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1363674202.844:241): arch=40000003 syscall=11 success=yes exit=0 a0=9ff7c38 a1=9ff7c00 a2=9ff6bd8 a3=9ff7c00 items=2 ppid=2593 pid=2594 auid=500 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key="apache-binary-file"
```

Comment: None of those things are running, but thanks for the useful tip on `auditd`. I'll try to solve this mystery with that!